# How can we know we are inside a spinlock?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I have a function which is called by multiple functions. Some functions call it with spinlock held and some without any lock. How can I know if my function is called with spinlock held?

I have a big piece of code written some time back. It has some functions which are called with and without locks from different code paths. The functions allocate skbs with GFP_KERNEL flag only considering the cases without locks. It is causing issues when called with spin_lock(). I need to handle both the cases to avoid sleeping inside a spin_lock.

Comment: What're you trying to decide based on this fact?

Comment: alloc_skb(size, GFP_KERNEL/GFP_ATOMIC);

Answer (score 5):

> How can I know if my function is called with spinlock held?

You cannot, not directly. You would need to set a flag in some structure yourself that indicates whether you hold the lock or not.

You are better off creating 2 functions. One that you call if you hold the lock, one that you call if you don't hold the lock.

```
//b->lck must be taken
void foo_unlocked(struct bar *b)
{
    //do your thing, assume relevant lock is held
}

//b->lck must not be taken
void foo(struct bar *b)
{
    spin_lock(b->lck);
    foo_unlocked(b);
    spin_unlock(b->lck);
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to call it `__foo` (Linux-style) or `foo_nolock` (Solaris-style?)

Answer (score 0):

I need to check only preemption disabled or irqs disabled. Based on that I can allocate memory with GFP_KERNEL or GFP_ATOMIC. Hence I don't need to rely on when spin_lock or another lock. Using in_atomic() and irqs_disabled() functions, I can achieve it. Thanks

Comment: I cannot judge if this actually works and is race free, but I can tell you that doing this is generally not a good idea. In C, and especially in low-level system programming, it is best to tell the programmer what options she has and let her choose what to do, or demand certain conditions and let her ensure those conditions, rather than try meet non-trivial conditions yourself. Like @nos said, the best solution is to have two functions, one assuming lock is taken and the other assuming not. Alternatively, you could take a `bool` value telling whether lock is taken.

Comment: The reason doing these things is not a good idea is that you force certain actions on a user that may be unnecessary, inefficient or just wrong. I don't know your application in particular, so this is general, but imagine the programmer calling your function in a context she knows would be ok to use `GFP_ATOMIC`, but for some reason the spinlock is not available, or shouldn't be taken.